# Is there a way I can combine two icons, one on top of the other, as the IconComponent in Table header using Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a table where I have an up/down triangle icon next to the column instead of default up arrow after the column name to indicate sorting. I went through the material-ui docs and read that the IconComponent prop can be used to give an icon other than the default, but I couldn't find a way to combine two icons, one on top of the other, and pass them in as the IconComponent prop.

[image: Table column showing the header text 'activity' with an up triangle icon and a down triangle icon stacked on top of each other]

Here is what I have tried on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/enhancedtable-material-demo-forked-6rsfi?file=/demo.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new component which is called `Icon`, which stacks the two icons using a flexbox container:

```js
const Icon = () => {
  return (
    <span
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "Center",
        alignItems: "Center",
        marginLeft: "5px"
      }}
    >
      <KeyBoardUpIcon fontSize="12" />
      <KeyBoardDownIcon fontSize="12" />
    </span>
  );
};
```

And use it as `IconComponent` prop in `TableSortLabel`s:

```
 <TableSortLabel
      active={true}
      direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
      IconComponent={Icon}
      onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
    >
```

[image: Edit EnhancedTable Material Demo (forked)]